# How to know if a C program supports an option

Tags: c, bash, getopt

I'm developing a script that checks the version of some installed C programs. The version check is performed with the --version option. However, this option may not be implemented in all the checked programs. When the option is implemented I use:

```
version=$(./$program_name --version)
```

But when it's not, the program just starts executing. 
If I just execute the program in the background and the stop it if continues running, I can never get the version number. Is there a way to check whether the option is implemented without letting the program run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to any arbitrary C program, no there is currently no way to reliably check if a program supports an option. You can try guessing with a mixture of `./program --help`, `./program --usage`, `./program -h` and `./program --this-option-is-a-lie-or-some-other-bogus-option-to-give-usage-information`. However, it all ultimately boils down to guesswork.

Answer (score 3):

Not completely waterproof but I nice start is using strings:

```
 strings /usr/bin/git | grep -- --version
```

Answer (score 0):

On RedHat and derivates using `yum` and `rpm` you can ask the rpm package manager:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /bin/cat
coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.1.i686
```

On Debian and derivated using `apt-get` you can ask the APT package manager:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /bin/bash 
bash: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day we always included a `what` string with version info.  Actually part of `SCCS`, if the program contained strings starting with "@(#)", it is displayed by the `what` command.  C code would like like this:

```
static char prog_id[] = "@(#) my_program  version 1.0 - 3/26/2014";
```

Anyway try doing a `what` on the program and see `what` you get.  heh.